# Download entire folder with Dropbox Chooser?

Tags: javascript, dropbox

Is it possible to download an entire folder using the Dropbox Chooser? It seems like you can only select files. I've read that you can get the metadata and download files individually, but I'd like to use this interface for the user to be able to select a folder.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Chooser only supports choosing individual files.

As a possible workaround, you can allow multiple selections, and then the user can select all the files within a folder.